Showing that the sum of exponentials is gamma distributed using the fourier transform
I am trying to use the result that $p(\omega)^n$ = Gamma(n, beta) where $p(\omega)$ is the fourier transform of an $Exp(\beta)$ distribution. My code does well for small n but as n increases the gamma starts to move across the domain faster. Here I have just set beta=1 for simplicity. I can not find the error in my code.
Note the mask is just to remove the horizontal Line artefact that often occurs after numerical fourier transforms.
I have pasted the code below.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#DETERMINISTIC CASE 

n = 15   # Scaling factor for the Fourier transform
N = 1024     # Number of points
T = 0.01     # Sampling interval
shift_point = 100 # Desired center of the plot

# Discretize the PDF
x_values = np.linspace(xm, 100, N, endpoint=False)
pdf_values = expon.pdf(x_values, scale=1)

# Numerical Fourier Transform of the Pareto PDF
P_omega = np.fft.fft(pdf_values)
# Scale and account for deterministic number of sources 
exp_nP = P_omega**(n)

# Compute the full frequency array for IFT
full_exp_nP = np.concatenate([exp_nP, np.conj(exp_nP[::-1])])

# Inverse Fourier Transform
ift_result = np.fft.ifft(full_exp_nP)
ift_result=ift_result[::2]
# Plotting

#Remove all small values
mask = ift_result > 0.01
ift_result = ift_result[mask]
x = np.fft.fftfreq(N, T)[mask]


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(x, -np.abs(ift_result)/np.trapz(x, np.abs(ift_result)), label = "fourier then inverse fourier ")
plt.title('Inverse Fourier Transform of exp(n * P(w)) Centered at 100 for Pareto Distribution')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.grid(True)
##TEST THE EXPONENTIAL DISTRIBUTION AS AN ALTENRATIVE TO THE PARETO. CHECKING HOW THE SUM OF EXPONENTIALS IS DISTRIBUTED. 

#GAMMA RV
x_gamma = np.arange(0, 50, 0.01)
y_gamma = gamma.pdf(x_gamma, n, scale=1)
plt.plot(x_gamma, y_gamma, label = "Gamma(n, beta)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()`

plot for n=10
Plot for n=30 shows significant deviation from gamma function

What is your question? (And, please, ensure that your code is reproducible. Is it a from scipy.stats import expon missing? Or another expon?

John, I can't quite tell what's going on with your code, but, having worked with similar problems in the past, my advice is to verify that you have the same increment between values for the exponential distributions as for the gamma. Also, bear in mind that if you start out with discretizing (0, max_x) for the exponentials, then after the FFT/IFFT operations, the range will go (0, n*max_x) for a sum of n exponentials -- make sure the range is the same for the gamma. Finally, normalize your sampled PDF's so that they sum to 1 -- this property should be preserved by FFT/IFFT.

Apologies, yes I am using expon and gamma from scipy.stats @chrslg

@RobertDodier I have normalised the exponential values however the issue still remains. As for the range, the range is defined using the fftfreq method, do you think this needs to be changed? This is a confusing part for me since raising N drastically changes the shape of the plot and I cant understand why.

@chrslg my question is why is the code not working well as n increases. The results for n<10 do very well and fit the gamma distribution almost perfectly however for n=20 for example there is a noticeable difference between the two distributions.

John, I'm sorry to hear you're running into problems, however, the way you are describing the problem, there is nothing for anyone else to do except run your code and study the output in detail. I think that's pretty unreasonable to expect from others, so you have to help others help you by showing exactly what you are getting and exactly in what way it diverges from what you expected.

Also, you might consider calling a convolution function instead of the FFT/IFFT since convolution is the operation that you are actually implementing here, and you might as well simplify your implementation by letting the convolution function handle some of the details.

@RobertDodier I have uploaded two images showing good results for n=10 and worse results for n=30.

Doesn't look so bad, to be honest. I assume the errors build up little by little. You can reduce the errors by making the grid resolution finer (try 0.001 or even smaller; FFT/IFFT is fast and memory is cheap, how about 1e-6?), or by reducing the number of FFT/IFFT operations (e.g. go by powers of 2, e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, then 30 = 16 + 8 + 4 + 2, so 7 operations in all instead of 30, or just look at 32 instead of 30).

I think the issue is actually just a result of not knowing how to properly define the domain x after the ift. In the code I have fftfreq however its not technically a frequency anymore. Also increasing N shift the plot to the far right so im not sure what the scale should be for the x points and how to define them. @RobertDodier

I have actually solved the issue. The problem like I thought was with defining the domain. using N = 1000000 and xmax =1000 the domain aligns correctly. I have no idea why but If i want to change xmax for example to 100, then i would need to divide my x vector by 100. And for example if xmax =40 then i need to divide by (1000/40)^2. No idea why this is. There is also dependence with N such that if I divide N by 10 then I need to multiply the x-vector by 10. Does anybody have an explanation for this.
